# Writing Social media's schema in dgraph

Tags: python, graph, graphql, dgraph

I am beginner with dgraph and shifting from neo4j to dgraph. I am writing schema where I have different social media platforms details.

Considering facebook, the schema will have basic details of the profile,groups,pages plus different relations between the fb profiles and groups and pages like

```
profile_a is 'friends_of' profile_b;
user 'likes' page_b;
user is 'member_of' group_a
user 'works_at' place_a
```

Similar case for twitter where the relations will be

```
twitter_user 'follows' user_a
user_a 'followed_by' users
```

What I have done so for

```
type Person{
        name: string @index(exact) .
        id: string @index(exact) .
        profile: string @index(exact) .
        picture_link: string .
        status_count: int .
        location: string .
        tags: string .
        user_id: int .
        follower_count: string .
        friend_count: string .
        type: int @index(exact) .   
        likes : [Page] .
        friends_of : [Fb_User] .
        members_of : [Group] .
        works_at : {
            name: string .
        }      
    }

    type Fb_User{
        name: string @index(exact) .
        id: string @index(exact) .
        profile: string @index(exact) .
        picture_link: string .
        status_count: int .
        location: string .
        type: int @index(exact) .  
        location: string .   
        tags: string .
        user_id: int .
    }

    type Group{
        name: string @index(exact) .
        id: string @index(exact) .
        profile: string @index(exact) .
        picture_link: string .
        group_member : int .

    }

    type Page{
        name: string @index(exact) .
        id: string @index(exact) .
        profile: string @index(exact) .
        picture_link: string .
        page_type : int .

    }

    type Facebook
     {  
        label: string @index(exact)  

    }
```

Kindly guide and correct me about schema structure. Looking forward to implement it in pydgraph

Thanks

Got help from
https://tour.dgraph.io/schema/1/

I expect a schema that will accept the basic details and relations via python code

Answer (score 0):

Based on the [example](https://tour.dgraph.io/schema/1/) you're referring to:

- in your case neither should it be necessary to define an `id` field on a type, nor make it a type `string`. The dgraph will assign a `uid` automatically. The indexing by `uid` is much faster.
- make sure to provide directives. For example, if you define a relation between a `Person` and a `Page` in the following way: `likes : [Page] .`, provide a directive of a form `likes: [uid] .` after your type definitions.

You could also consider trying a [GraphQL version](https://graphql.dgraph.io) of the Dgraph, so you can build relationships with the GraphQL SDL, which would make them reusable in your app.